# Access a value within an array AngularJS

Tags: arrays, angularjs, loops, foreach

I'm trying to use first objects of the array. I'm not sure how to access value of the screenItem. I've tried many different things but all I get is 'undefined' or 'object'. Please take a look at the hierarchy in the image provided.

[image]
This is how far I got

```
  var log = [];

  angular.forEach(serviceReply, function(value, key){
    console.log(key + ': ' + value.screenItem);
  });
```

serviceReply is defined like this

```
var serviceReply = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
```

Comment: can you please share the data within array?

Comment: It's visible on the image.
{screenItem: "RENAMEDOC", screenItemDescription: "Edit Document Filename"}
{screenItem: "DELETEDOC", screenItemDescription: "Delete Document"}

Comment: what is the output of console.log you are logging.. ?

Comment: 'Envelope: undefined'. I'm trying to get: RENAMEDOC and DELETEDOC

Comment: your data is inside `serviceReply.Envelope.Body.getHiddenScreenItemsResponse.return.item`  right.. ?

Comment: Looks like it. item being so far gets me confused on how to access it...

Comment: can you share your SOAP response which you are receiving from the service... ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/csrnzoxj/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I took. Couldn't find a different working answer.

```
for (var i = 0; i < serviceReply.Envelope.Body.getHiddenScreenItemsResponse.return.item.length; i++) {
    roles.push(serviceReply.Envelope.Body.getHiddenScreenItemsResponse.return.item[i].screenItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
angular.forEach(serviceReply.SMART.XMLJSON, function(value, key){
       console.log(key + ': ' + value.screenItem);
});
```

Comment: So, try this: `angular.forEach(serviceReply, function(value, key){
    console.log(key + ': ' + value.Envelope.BodygetHiddenScreenItemsResponse.return.item.screenItem);
  });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
angular.forEach(serviceReply, function(value, key){ console.log(key + ': ' + value.Envelope.BodygetHiddenScreenItemsResponse.return.item.‌​screenItem); });
```